# Working USB wifi 802.11n 5GHz network adapter in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, usb, networking

Does anybody have a personal recommendation for a USB wifi network adapter that:

1. has decent Linux drivers
2. supports 802.11n speeds
3. will connect to a wifi signal in the 5GHz band?

I've spent some time in google, the Ubuntu hardware compatibility pages and reading through various launchpad bug trails about support for the ralink chipset variations being a bit spotty.

I'm really finding it difficult to see any clear choice for me to purchase, so could do with a nudge in the right direction.

It would be ideal if it worked out of the box with kernel drivers, but I'll mess around with ndiswrapper etc if required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions for wireless adapters to work most (if not all) on the 802.11g or 802.11n specification in the 2.4 GHz band. I had no succces finding any adapters we know for sure that they work in a dual band setting on 5 GHz.

This may be just bad luck or insufficient search capability on my side but just in case nobody else leaves a positive message her I recommend you run your wireless network using an external adapter that transforms the wireless 5GHz signal into a Ethernet network signal. By this you will be able to enjoy **OS and driver independent** wireless networking.

Here I have only experience with a [Buffalo AirStation WLI-TX4-AG300N](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/client-adapters/airstation-nfiniti-wireless-n-dual-band-ethernet-converter-wli-tx4-ag300n/) that works like a charm but there are a few other good products available.

Comment: Thanks Takkat, I wasn't aware of things like that - will be a good fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the ath9k driver is pretty good and I haven't had many problems with the intel-pro 5100agn chipsets(I see a lot of people get a little upset with them, but it's never gone so horribly wrong that a reboot didn't fix it.  Most of the Intel driver issues are related to power mgmt/resume from suspend).  I no longer have the N capability disabled(it didn't used to work.  now it does.)